# JQuery run function from select menu on the default option

Tags: jquery, forms

Let's say you have a select menu that does some sort of jQuery when an option is selected

```
<select class="doThis">
    <option selected="selected">Do This</option>
    <option>Do That</option>
    <option>Do That Other Thing</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery that will run it is something like this:

```
$(".doThis").change(function () {
     //Code
});
```

That is all well and good, but how do you get the function to run if some uses the drop down menu to select the option that is already selected? The "Do This" option. Since "Do This" is already, there is no change and the function won't fire. How can I make this fire?

Comment: What do you need it to do, exactly?

Comment: Clicking on an already selected option doesn't fire any events anyway.

Comment: I am trying to run a function when the option that is already selected in the select menu is reselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`$(".doThis option").on('click',function(){
})`

Or

have your function and add this function too:

`$(".doThis option[selected=selected]").click(function(){})`